# Whats wrong with this simple MySQL CREATE TABLE statement?

Tags: mysql

I encounter this error when creating a table. How can it be fixed?

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE Measurement(

MeasurementID NOT NULL ,
MeasurementTypeID INTEGER,
MeasurementNameCHAR( 100 ) ,
SemanticModelInfrastructureID INTEGER,
AddressCHAR( 150 ) ,
PRIMARY BOOL,
DerivedCalcCHAR( 255 ) ,
PRIMARY KEY ( MeasurementID ) ,
KEY ( MeasurementTypeID ) ,
KEY ( SemanticModelInfrastructureID )
);
```

MySQL said:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL,
    MeasurementTypeID INTEGER,
    MeasurementName CHAR(100),
    SemanticMo' at line 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors:

You need to give `MeasurementID` a data type before the `null`/`not null` declataration

```
MeasurementID int unsigned not null auto_increment,
```

You're missing spaces before `CHAR` on a few lines.

`PRIMARY` is a reserved word and needs to be surrounded with backtics (on the `PRIMARY BOOL` line)

Comment: Thanks NOw shome another error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BOOL, DerivedCalc CHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (MeasurementID), KEY (Measurement' at line 8

Comment: @user2293171 you didn't surround `PRIMARY` in backticks like I said to, did you?  `\`PRIMARY\` BOOL`

Answer (score 2):

MeasurementID has no type; try `MeasurementID INTEGER NOT NULL`.

Comment: Thanks NOw shome another error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BOOL, DerivedCalc CHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (MeasurementID), KEY (Measurement' at line 8

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the data type here:

```
MeasurementID NOT NULL
```

Try:

```
MeasurementID INTEGER NOT NULL
```

NOT NULL is just a constraint that prevents NULL values being stored a column. You still need to declare desired data type, like INTEGER or CHAR.

Comment: Thanks NOw shome another error
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BOOL,
    DerivedCalc CHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (MeasurementID),
    KEY (Measurement' at line 8